# Is it possible to configure compile option for libs installed from apt-get?

Tags: 14.04, apt, compiling

After installing wxwidgets by running

`sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-*`

I wanted to compile opennx against it. However, I received a message

> Your wxWidgets does not provide the required wxLogStream class. 
>   Please reconfigure wxWidgets using the option --enable-std_iostreams

After compile wxWidgets from source, I got it running.

I wonder, can I use apt-get to install libs, and configure some options? Or do I have to build it from source?

Comment: Just fyi the wxLogStream test passes on my 14.04 installation with libwxgtk3.0-dev 3.0.0-2 from the standard repository

Answer (score 0):

If you install a package via apt, than you cant't change the options (keyword `Makefile`) for the compiler because you install one or more binaries.

So you have to recompile if you want that a particular option is added or removed.

Alternatively, you can search a PPA that is better suited to your needs.